# Flash AS3 get time in another timezone

Tags: actionscript-3, date, flash

I need to make a countdown clock to a certain time in New York in Flash AS3, regardless of the user's local machine time. I can do the clock itself once i have the Date object correct, but I can't seem to figure out how to create a Date object with the time in New York. I'll have to keep in mind Daylight Savings Time as well.

any help is appreciated. thanks.

Comment: http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/Date.html

Comment: At first, I thought the date docs would trivially answer this question, but it turns out to be a pretty complex task.  There's no Date constructor for an arbitrary locale, implying that you'd need to get a date for the current locale, get UTC date from that, and then manually calculate the difference to New York...kind of an awkward dance to get to what you're trying to do!

Comment: @Brian exactly. :) not easy. that was my thought too. but still having trouble executing it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

after yet another google search, i finally found the solution [here](http://www.andygup.net/figuring-out-date-time-zones-in-adobe-flexactionscript/).

```
var now:Date = new Date();
trace("now local time: " + now);

var newYorkOffset:int = 1000 * 60 * 60 * 5; // 5 hours offset for NYC 
var localTimezoneOffset:Number = now.getTimezoneOffset() * 60 * 1000;

// add now + localTimeZoneOffset to get UTC, then subtract NY offset to get NY time      
now.setTime(now.getTime() + localTimezoneOffset - newYorkOffset);           
trace("now in New York: " + now);
```

and i'm pretty sure that this takes daylight savings into account, since `getTimezoneOffset()` includes daylight savings automatically based on the date.

to test, temporarily change your machine's timezone to something other than New York. "now in New York:" time will not change.